# Backend Spring-Boot and FE React - 404 error for PUT:/update whereas other CRUD operations are working

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-status-code-404, put

I'm working on a Spring Boot application with a React frontend. I have an endpoint `/employees/update` that's supposed to update an employee record when a `PUT` request is made. However, I'm getting a 404 error when I try to access this endpoint.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// Employee.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

}
```

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeJpaRepository employeeJpaRepository;

    @Override
    public Employee updateEmployeeById(long employeeId, Employee updatedEmployee) {
        Employee existingEmployee = this.findEmployeeById(employeeId);
        existingEmployee.setFirstName(updatedEmployee.getFirstName());
        existingEmployee.setLastName(updatedEmployee.getLastName());
        existingEmployee.setEmail(updatedEmployee.getEmail());
        return this.employeeJpaRepository.save(existingEmployee);
    }
```

```
// EmployeeController.java
    package com.abj.EmpMgmtSys.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
// import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
//import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

import com.abj.EmpMgmtSys.model.Employee;
import com.abj.EmpMgmtSys.service.EmployeeService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:5173")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeController.class);

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public ResponseEntity<?> listEmployees() {
        Set<Employee> employees = this.employeeService.fetchAll();
        logger.info("Fetched employees: {}", employees); // Log the fetched employees
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employees);
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public Employee saveEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return this.employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
    }

    @PutMapping("/update")
    public Employee updateEmployee(@RequestParam("id") long employeeId, @RequestBody Employee updatedEmployee) {
        logger.info("Received update request for employee with ID: {}", employeeId);

        return employeeService.updateEmployeeById(employeeId, updatedEmployee);
    }

    @PostMapping("/delete")
    public void deleteEmployeeById(@RequestParam("id") long employeeId) {
        this.employeeService.deleteEmployeeById(employeeId);
    }

    @GetMapping("/search")
    public Set<Employee> searchEmployees(@RequestParam("keyword") String keyword) {
        return employeeService.searchEmployees(keyword);
    }

    @GetMapping("/list-sorted/{sortOrder}")
    public List<Employee> listEmployeesSorted(@PathVariable String sortOrder) {
        if ("desc".equals(sortOrder)) {
            return employeeService.getAllEmployeesSortedByFirstNameDesc();
        } else {
            return employeeService.getAllEmployeesSortedByFirstName();
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:5173")); // Allow frontend origin
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        // ...
    }

    // ...
    .antMatchers("/login", "/loginPage*").permitAll() 
    .antMatchers("/employees/list").permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/employees/save").permitAll()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/employees/update").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/employees/delete").permitAll() 
}
```

When I start the application and make a `PUT` request to `http://localhost:5173/employees/update` with a valid `id` and `Employee` object, I expect the employee to be updated and the updated employee to be returned. However, I get a 404 error instead. Error updating employee AxiosError

Interestingly, other endpoints like `http://localhost:5173/employees/delete` and `http://localhost:5173/employees/save` are working fine.

Here's the project link for reference: [https://github.com/harihargithub/EmpMgmtSys].

Backend: mpMgmtSys_sboot_vite_react_mysql_sf> mvn install clean then mvn spring-boot:run  (Port:8080)

Frontend: EmpMgmtSys_sboot_vite_react_mysql_sf\empvitereact>npm install then run dev  (Port:5173)

@ empvitereact/src/main.jsx - // .env - VITE_SYNCFUSION_LICENSE_KEY='Your SF Licence Key'
registerLicense(import.meta.env.VITE_SYNCFUSION_LICENSE_KEY); or you may include your license directly here.

Does anyone know why I might be getting a 404 error for the `/employees/update` endpoint?

---

Comment: `EmployeeServiceImpl` only handles PUT, but it doesn't appear to map to the `/employees` endpoint. I think you may have another service for `/employees` which is handling the other verbs.

Comment: Edit your question instead of providing information in comments.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of providing information in comments.

Comment: Noted with thanks & done.

Comment: The part of your system with the problem is `EmployeeController` and yet you show almost none of it.

Comment: I understand that the EmployeeController is central to the issue, but due to the extensive codebase, I've opted for a MRE format here. However, I've provided a link to the full project for comprehensive analysis which I am sharing again - [harihargithub/EmpMgmtSys] and kindly note that empvitereact/src/main.jsx needs Syncfusion License.

Comment: Questions should be self contained. What does MRE mean?

Comment: Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)

Comment: Have you provided an MRE?

Comment: Could not create a proper MRE hence shared the Project GitHub link itself

Comment: The symptom of your problem is different behaviour between the PUT endpoint and other endpoints, yet the configuration of those endpoints on the service is exactly what you've left out. Few people are going to go to GitHub to look at your code.

Comment: I shall wait for the response from those who look at entire code accessing the GitHub link. Meantime, I have edited the body and included the complete EmployeeController code.

Comment: Success!

Changes made to /update @ EmployeeController.java, EmployeeService.java, EmployeeList.jsx and vite.config.js and now all CRUD operations including update are working fine after repeated trail & error.

Push to harihargithub/EmpMgmtSys done.

Thanks & Regards//Harihar.N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success!

Changes made to /update @ EmployeeController.java, EmployeeService.java, EmployeeList.jsx and vite.config.js and now all CRUD operations including update are working fine after repeated trail & error.

Push to harihargithub/EmpMgmtSys done.

Thanks & Regards